# Incorrect partial being rendered in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been stumped as to why my rails app is rendering the wrong partial. I have two partials, each related to a different controller (invitations and guests controllers). One partial lists the number of invitations sent out to users and the second partial lists those users who have confirmed their invitation. In addition, the second partial also allows one to see a simple profile of the confirmed guests.

What is happening is that when I visit the link related to the guests controller `events/1/guests/`, I expect to see the partial related to the guest profile. Instead, the partial related to the invitations controller is rendered. Both the invitations and guests controllers are nested resources of events.

Below is the code that I have been working with. Thanks!

Routes

```
resources :events, only: [:new, :show, :create] do
    resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create, :show]
    resources :guests, only: :show
end

match '/events/:id/guests', to: 'guests#show'
```

Guests controller

```
def show
   @event = Event.find_by_id(params[:id])
   @guestlist = @event.invitations.where(accepted: true)
end
```

views/guests/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @event.eventname + " Guest List") %>
<h1> Guest list for <%= @event.eventname %> </h1>

<% if @event.invitations.any? %>
   <%= render @guestlist %>
<% end %>
```

views/guests/_guestlist.html.erb

```
<li>
<%= guestlist.name %> | <%= guestlist.occupation %> | 
    <%= guestlist.interests %>  
</li>
```

Instead, the following partial is being rendered:

views/invitations/_invitation.html.erb

```
<li>
<%= invitation.name %> | <%= invitation.email %> | 
<% if invitation.accepted == true %> <%= "Confirmed" %> <% else %> <%= "Pending" %> <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet depicts the correct way to invoke your partial:

```
# app/views/guests/show.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'guests/guestlist', :locals => {:guestlist => @guestlist} %>
```

Since you need access to the `@guestlist` instance variable in your partial, you'll need to pass it as a local. Then, in your partial, `guestlist` will be available as a local variable.

Then, within your partial, you'll need to iterate over the members of your guestlist:

```
# app/views/guests/_guestlist.html.erb
<% guestlist.each do |guest| %>
    <li> 
         <%= guest.name %> | <%= guest.occupation %> | <%= guest.interests %>  
    </li>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

The reason the OP's original invocation of the partial rendered the `invitation` partial is that `@guestlist` is actually comprised of `Invitation` objects, and thus, the `<%= render @guestlist %>` method was actually looking for a partial named `invitation`. From the canonical Rails guides:

> There is also a shorthand for this. Assuming @products is a collection
>   of product instances, you can simply write this in the index.html.erb
>   to produce the same result:

```
<h1>Products</h1> 
<%= render @products %>
```

> Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the
>   model name in the collection.

Because of this, you need to explicitly declare the name of the partial you want to use, otherwise ActionView will use the `invitation` partial by default.

Comment: I dont think `@guestlist` need to be passed in from locals as it should be automatically available in the partial.

Comment: @user1541507, that is absolutely incorrect. Can you cite any documentation pursuant to your claim?

Comment: Instance variables are directly accessible in your rails views. Tried and used this several times. Simple.

Comment: `guestlist` must be passed as a local, however the instance variable `@guestlist` could be used instead without passing it as a local - it is usually better in the long run to pass all data to partials as locals - IMO

Comment: @house9. very right, evidently. Have grown so accustomed to passing in variables as locals that I forgot about this. I agree that – as a matter of convention – it is indeed best practice to pass variables to partials as locals.

Comment: @house9 Even I have heard this thing several times that using instance vars in partial is bad practice but, I have failed to understand how using this is fine otherwise except in partials. I have read the rails-bestpractices blog. Its like one extra variable in memory for me. It will be great if you can share cons of using them in partials.

Comment: @zeantsoi, thanks. This did the trick. I am a little confused about the two code snippets you suggested. First, in regards to `guests/show.html.erb` what is the different between what I had and your suggestions? It seems to be that your solution is a little more explicit? Any idea why my code produced the wrong partial? Second, is it necessary to iterate over the guest lists? My invitations partial, `invitations/_invitation.html.erb` works fine without a do loop. If anything, can you point in the right direction so that I can learn about these mistakes?

Comment: @bryant, I've updated my answer to include an explanation to the first of your questions. As to why the `invitations` partial worked without a loop, I'm unsure. Intuitively, I wouldn't think it'd work without looping, but perhaps your template contains some interceding code that is passing in an iterable object. At any rate, I think you're well advised to explicitly loop the desired object.

Comment: @user1541507 - for me it comes down to maintenance, not using instance variables allows you to avoid nil exceptions (which can be hard to track down);
as your app grows soon you end up using the same partial in more than one view and often need data from multiple instance variables, things get messy fast.
I usually try to limit the number of instance variables in views as well, not just the partials.

Comment: @house9, +1 for the nice explanation !

Answer (score 1):

If `@guestlist` is an object of type `Guest`, then it would by default render `_guest.html.erb`.

So, you can try This

```
<%= render 'guestlist' %>
```

Variable `@guestlist` would be automatically available in the partial, so no need to pass it in locals.

Hope this works.

Comment: i think it would be `<%= render @guest_list %>`, not sure why the down vote? - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Answer (score 0):

In your show action, you have defined

```
@guestlist = @event.invitations.where(accepted: true) # it returns array of obejects or records
```

Now, Please have a try with the following code

views/guests/show.html.erb

```
<% unless @guestlist.blank? %>
   <%= render "/guests/guestlist" %>
<% end %>
```

views/guests/_guestlist.html.erb

```
<% @guestlist.each do |guestlist| %>
 <li>
  <%= guestlist.name %> | <%= guestlist.occupation %> | 
    <%= guestlist.interests %>  
 </li>
<% end %>
```